# RecyclerView scroll to position when a new item is added

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I want my RecyclerView to scroll to the bottom when a new item is added to the list. Below is my code:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(data, recyclerView);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And when I click a button which is below the `RecyclerView`, data is added to the list:

```
public void addNewCard() {
    data.add("New");
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(data.size() - 1);
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(data.size() - 1);
}
```

Whenever I add an item, it always gets scrolled up to the topmost position. I tried using `smoothScrollToPosition()` and tried using `scrollToPosition()` on `LinearLayoutManager` too. I even tried using `ViewTreeObserver`. Tried changing the version of `RecyclerView` in dependencies too. I searched thoroughly on Stack Overflow and none of the solutions work for me.

Any ideas on what could be the problem? I'm using `RecyclerView` inside a fragment. Could that be a cause of the problem?

My .xml file for the `RecyclerView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroll_view_recycler"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add_new_card"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/listView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="+ Add new Item" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Are you using RecyclerView inside ScrollView?

Comment: @Deepa yes I'm using it inside a RelativeLayout which is inside a ScrollView

Comment: Then try to use NestedSrollView instead of ScrollView. Or use this method for RecyclerView                              layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

Comment: @Deepa tried both. Doesn't work! :(

Comment: Are you using GridLayoutManager? In that case it will not support setStackFromEnd().

Comment: No. I'm using LinearLayoutManager.

Comment: Ok then try to use this in your RecyclerViewAdapter.                               @Override
public Item getItem(int pos) {
return super.getItem(getCount() - 1 - pos);
}

Comment: @Deepa sorry, I don't get that. There isn't any `getItem(int pos)` method in `RecyclerView.Adapter` class to override!

Comment: Put your Adapter class.

Comment: It still doesn't work!

Comment: Post your Adapter class here.

Comment: @Deepa Ok, edited!

Comment: Ok if you add getItem() then what is happening ?

Comment: @Deepa What should I return with `getItem` method? Because there is no `Item` type.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If want to add the data to the bottom of the list you need to use `setStackFromEnd()` in RecyclerView Layout Manager.

But first, you need to fix your Adapter. You must not pass your RecylerView to your Adapter. So the following code is wrong:

```
...
// This is wrong!!
adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(data, recyclerView);

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You need to change your Adapter constructor to only receive the data as its parameter. Something like this:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

  private List<Data> mData;

  public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Data> data) {
    this.mData = data;
  }

  ...
}
```

Then you can set the data to always added at the last bottom with the following code:

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(data);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To add the new data, you better to make a new method in the adapter. Something like this:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

  private List<Data> mData;
  ...

  public void addItem(Data datum) {
    mData.add(datum);
    notifyItemInserted(mData.size());
  }
}
```

Whenever you have adding a new data, you need to scroll to the bottom with `scrollToPosition` method. Something like this:

```
adapter.addItem(newData);
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
```

Remember that you need to override `getItemCount()` in your Adapter. It should be something like this:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

  private List<Data> mData;
  public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Data> data) {
    this.mData = data;
  }

  // Return the total count of items
  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
  }

  ...
}
```

Please be aware that I'm using a Data pojo as a sample here. You need to change it according to your data type.

Comment: Thank you. But I have tried this and it doesn't work!

Comment: What doesn't work? can you create a simple project just for only the RecyclerView and adapter. I'm using the above code in my project.

Comment: I have added my .xml file including the `RecyclerView`. Can you see if there's a problem with it?

Comment: You are right. I created a simple project and did the same with `RecyclerView` and `RecyclerView.Adapter`. It works fine. Apparently the problem is somewhere else. I'll look at it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Glad it help you a little bit! Good luck on your endeavor ;)

Comment: Hey @ישואוהבאותך can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952965/recyclerview-horizontal-scrolling-to-left?noredirect=1#comment87861669_49952965

Answer (score 15):

This was the solution I came up with, which was good enough for the basics, and didn't require any custom adapters.

```
myAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object :
        RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            myRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart)
        }
    })
```

Comment: In case you are using paging, check for `positionStart != 0` and then scroll

Answer (score 9):

```
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
        super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount)

        val msgCount = adapter.getItemCount()
        val lastVisiblePosition = 
            linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

        if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 || positionStart >= msgCount - 1 && 
            lastVisiblePosition == positionStart - 1) {
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart)
        } else {
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you are using ListAdapter with DiffUtill and submit new list through `submitList()`, you could use ListAdapter's `onCurrentListChanged`. For example:

```
override fun onCurrentListChanged(previousList: MutableList<Item>, currentList: MutableList<Item>) {
    super.onCurrentListChanged(previousList, currentList)
     //E.g. check if new item has been added
    if (currentList.size == previousList.size + 1) {
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(currentList.size - 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ישו אוהב אותך's solution worked on other projects. But setting `recyclerView.scrollToPosition()` didn't work for me. This is what finally did the job:

```
public void addNewCard() {
    data.add("New");
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(data.size());

    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.scrollTo(0,buttonAddNewItem.getTop());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help someone

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
    if (pingAdapter != null) {

        Ping ping = dataSnapshot.getValue(Ping.class);
        pingAdapter.pings.add(ping);
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(pingAdapter.getItemCount());

        pingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(pingAdapter.pings.size());
```

is even faster

Comment: I can't locate **onChildAdded** or **DataSnapshot** in RecyclerView's source

Comment: Because it is a method by com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.addChildEventListener, not RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

It took me quite some time to get Recycler View to scroll to show the new added item. I got it to work by adding scrollToPosition in the Observer of the list of items coming from database. Here is my approach:

```
viewModel.itemList.observe(this, Observer { list ->
    list?.let {
        val numNewItems = it.size - recyclerViewAdapter.itemCount
        recyclerViewAdapter.updateList(it)
        /* Scroll to top to show new item if one was added */
        if (numNewItems >  0) {
            // position could be it.size - 1 for bottom or 0 for top
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position)
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your

recyclerView.scrollToPosition(data.size() - 1);

is getting called first and then the list is being initialized. You need to add this line after your recycler View view is initialized. You can add this line in a handler.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        override fun onChanged() {
            super.onChanged()
            if (canShowLive()) wvl_log_rv.scrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount - 1)
        }
 })
```

> Tested & Verified