# RecyclerView - Scrolling down when new item is inserted

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When my recyclerview gets a new item inserted using notifyItemInserted and smoothScrollToPosition, it creates a flickering/blink effect. What is causing it? I just want it to scrollDown when a new item is inserted.

```
 mMessageList.add(messageObject);
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {                            
       mChatMessageAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mMessageList.size());                    
       mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mMessageList.size());                            
     }
 });
```

Comment: You can follow this link. It would be helpful. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250907/recyclerview-scroll-to-position-when-a-new-item-is-added

Comment: @MuktaGhosh Thanks for the link. Apparently I was missing "-1" at the end of smoothScrollToPosition(mMessageList.size()). That fixed that flickering problem

Comment: Yes you are. Welcome.

Comment: `notifyItemInserted` also should have -1, and also `smoothScrollToPosition` should be made inside some `post` giving some time for `notifyItemInserted` to work (it may need to draw this new item if you are on the bottom)