# How to update data in recyclerview, after add new item in list. Using Pagination

Tags: android, kotlin, pagination, android-room

I use paging component v3, more specifically remote mediator, where I add a new item to the list and the recycler-view doesn't show the item, I have to scroll down the list to see the item. Is there a way to update the view? I use pagination with internet and database

Comment: recyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);

You can fire it with a callback after inserting a new item into the adapter.

Comment: take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63374478/6751083)

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve my doubt.